# Does python have a dict like container but fast like numpy.array?

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

I know numpy.array is much faster and cost much less memory than the python built-in list. 
Is there something dict like but much faster ? I only need to store `int` : `int` or `int` : `float` data.

Comment: First of all, python lists are fast for the type of data structure they represet -- a list [not an array]. I think python dictionaries are pretty efficient at the data structure they are supposed to represent: an associative array.

Comment: Secondly, not sure what your use case is, but perhaps you can use spare-matrices from numpy? [coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) uses integer indices to only represent parts of matrix data

Comment: @Dhara What Python calls a list is simply an array, albeit a dynamic one (here, dynamic refers to the size, not to the types of items).

Comment: @delnan A python list can hold different (dynamic) data types, whereas a numpy array can not.

Comment: @Dhara: yes, but delnan is right, a `list` is an array at the C level. An array of pointers, that is.

Comment: @Dhara Yes, but that does not make it "not an array". It makes it less efficient than numpy arrays due to more indirection and more type checking. But it's still an array and there is no difference in asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Dhara: Actually, you *can* create a numpy array of arbitrary python objects.

Comment: @zhangalin: It is not always true that "numpy array is much faster...".  For short sequences, lists can be much faster than numpy arrays.  The performance depends on the size of the arrays and what you are doing with them.  root's simple question about the usecase (first comment) is important.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser how? By defining my own dtype?

Comment: @Dhara: dtype=object will do it, e.g.: `x = array(['hello', [3,None], dict(foo='bar')], dtype=object)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks, learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at `series` from [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html). As you can see from the examples, it works  well with `np.arrays`:

```
import numpy as np

from pandas import *

randn = np.random.randn

In [309]: s = Series(randn(5), index=randn(5))

In [310]: s
Out[310]: 
 1.968290    0.132438
-0.307750    0.158168
 0.288507    2.129288
 1.002813   -0.247056
-0.450041    1.731273

In [311]: foo = np.array([0., 1.5, 1.])

In [312]: s = Series(foo)

In [313]: s
Out[313]: 
0    0.0
1    1.5
2    1.0
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see a timing comparison with the built in dictionary type, since the OP asked for a faster implementation

Comment: @root you can have ints as keys in the builtin dictionary type as well

Comment: @ Dhara: yes you are right, and i even checked the perfomance, if you just want to retrive values by key, using a dict is the best choice, being at least two order of magnitudes faster. So if thats, the usecase, dict's are the way to go.